# не получается добавить кнопку закрыть в модальное окно js

Tags: javascript

При открытии модального окна не показывается кнопка. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать кнопку закрытия в модальном окне

```js
const data = [
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
      "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
      "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
    },
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
      "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
      "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
    },
    {
      "postId": 1,
      "id": 3,
      "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
      "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
      "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
    }];


function callback (a) {
    const tr =  `
    <tr>
    <td> ${a.postId}</td>
    <td> ${a.id} </td>
    <td> ${a.name} </td>
    <td> ${a.email} </td>
    <td class="bubu"> ${a.body} </td>
    <td class="btn"> <a href="#">Редактировать</a> </td>
    </tr>
    `
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML += tr;
    
};

data.forEach(callback);

var bubu = document.getElementsByClassName('bubu');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')
const modal = document.getElementById('modal');

for(let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
  btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    modal.innerText = bubu[i].innerText;
    modal.style.display = 'block';
    });
};
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: solid 1px black;
}

#modal {
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid blue;
  width: 444px;
  height: 444px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: fixed;
  color: red;
}

#close {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <title>JS-HW-5-6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Сторінка коментарів</h1>
 <div contenteditable="true" id="modal">
    <div id="close" data-close>&times;</div>
 </div>
 
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>postId</th>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>body</th>
            <th>Редактировать</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="root"></tbody>
    </table>    
    <script src="./data.js"></script>
    <script src="./script3.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что из этого является модальным окном?

Comment: Потому что `modal.innerText = bubu[i].innerText;` заменяет весь контент внутри `#modal` удаляя в том числе и кнопку закрытия.

Comment: @SwaD, div c id=modal

Comment: @Simon , а что тогда использовать, чтоб текст выводило, поджскажите

Comment: Используйте appendChild().

Comment: @Никитос спасибо, всё получилось!

Answer (score 0):

добавил кнопку с помощью appendChild()